# How can I center my logo for my mobile site?

Tags: css, mobile, responsive-design, alignment, graphical-logo

I’m trying to horizontally center my logo on for my mobile version of my site. I can’t get it to center, though. I’ve tried various things but nothing seems to move it.

My code is:

```
    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) { .logo-image .logo img { 
    max-height: 70px;
    margin-top: -15px;
    margin-bottom: 15px;
    width: auto;
    background: center;
}
}
```

Comment: Could you provide the associated HTML markup?

Comment: its a template based site (squarespace) with custom CSS that I have added, so im not sure how to get you that. My site is http://jeffreydowellphotography.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `h1.logo` try `text-align:center;`

Comment: Thank you Sir! Is it ok to ask another question here? I would like to get rid of the large gaps of white space between the two shaded lines for all pages of my site. Its wasted space.

Comment: remove #pageWrapper { margin-top: 30px; } I will let you figure out the other one.

Comment: if i remove that, then the spacing looks bad for desktop version of site. I tried adding":    @media only screen and (max-width: 640px) {
   #pageWrapper { 
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;}
}

Comment: my apologies, i didnt specify for mobile only in my second question above